# Parallel-test Cucumber watir testing with phantomjs ECONREFUSED

Tags: cucumber, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I`m having issues with phantomjs with my parallel testing, firefox is running fine. I use parallel_tests, watir-webdriver, and Cucumber.

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8910 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Tests are running via:

`parallel_cucumber features/parallel_tests -n 3`

After some debugging I figured the problem appears when first process is finished with testing, it somehow kills all phantomjs browser instances.

This is env.rb setup:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, args: %w(--ignore-ssl-errors=true)

Before do
  @browser = browser
  @browser.cookies.clear
end

at_exit do
  browser.close
end
```

I also tried not closing browser at all, but with no luck, it is somehow done automatically. 
I tried both Windows, and CentOS.

```
phantomjs -v 
2.0.0
Using cucumber 1.3.19
Using selenium-webdriver 2.45.0
Using watir-webdriver 0.6.11
Using parallel 1.4.1
Using parallel_tests 1.3.9
```

I have a feeling it is a phantomjs/webdriver bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a race condition to port 8910 by your 3 phantom instances. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859919/opening-several-threads-with-watir-webdriver-results-in-connection-refused-err/26867830#26867830) issue.

```
# env.rb
Before do
  sleep ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'].to_i
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, args: %w(--ignore-ssl-errors=true)
end
```

If I'm reading the ParallelTests source correctly, environment variable TEST_ENV_NUMBER is set to the process index for each process. So the first process has a TEST_ENV_NUMBER of 0. As long as that's the case, the Before hook above will sleep for that number of seconds before initializing Watir::Browser. That will stagger the the parallelization a bit, but it should remove the race condition.

Comment: I read that question, it will probably be something simillar, but the problem is not with starting the phantom, but with killing it.

Tests run fine for 3 minutes, but when 1st process is finished it kills all phantoms.

Comment: Ok, So I tried `sleep ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'].to_i`, and this time only the last tests failed.

... 
some more testing, 
I added it to two places, and it passed... weird...

Comment: So you were right, but my env.rb had something before browser setup, so even 1s sometimes wasn`t sufficient,anyway THANKS A LOT!!!